# How to deploy nuxt.js project on shared hosting?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is it possible to deploy nuxt-js spa project in shared hosting like hostgator through cpanel?

I have tried several time to run below command, it's generate dist folder but didn't work.

My command: `npm run build`

Can you help me please?

Comment: post the details of nuxt.config.js file

Answer (score 8):

```
npm run build
```

Builds files for `npm run start` serving. And looks like you want it to be static files, which you just upload to hosting. So you should run:

```
npm run generate
```

then in `/dist/` you will find static spa.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to deploy Nuxt SPA to shared hosting. You can follow the official documentation of Nuxt.

- [Nuxt Latest: Documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#static-hosting)
- [Nuxt V2: Documentation](https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/features/deployment-targets#static-hosting)

Step by step to get the file of generate:

- `npm run build`
- `npm run generate`
- the result generated you can see in the folder `/dist` all assets of the folder `dist` can be uploaded/deploy to your shared hosting.

Thank you maybe can help.