# deploy Nuxt.js project on plesk web host?

Tags: web-deployment, plesk, shared-hosting, plesk-onyx

I want to deploy my nuxt.js project on a windows server, `plesk` shared web host.

I have done the following steps:

1. I have build project using 'node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt-start'
2. copy .next folder to httpdocs folder in server
3. copy 'nuxt.config.js' to httpdocs folder
4. copy 'package.json' to httpdocs folder
5. deleted web.config file
6. In the field Application Startup File you have to put  node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt-start
7. installed npm packeges on server

but it does not run on the server and I get the following error:

> This site can’t be reached

what is wrong?

What are the correct steps to deploy `nuxt` project on `plesk`?

Thank you

Comment: I have checked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218222/how-to-start-nuxt-js-on-plesk and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021173/how-to-deploy-nuxt-js-project-on-shared-hosting

Comment: improved formatting and grammar

Comment: refer to end part of this link: https://github.com/pi0/nuxt-plesk-example.